# How to move a command handler to another file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I found a custom routed command example form the [Microsoft Examples](https://github.com/Microsoft/WPF-Samples/blob/master/Input%20and%20Commands/CustomRoutedCommand/MainWindow.cs), It works well.

```xml
<Window x:Class="CustomRoutedCommand.MainWindow"
        ...
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomRoutedCommand">
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:MainWindow.ColorCmd}"
                    Executed="ColorCmdExecuted"
                    CanExecute="ColorCmdCanExecute"/>
    </Window.CommandBindings>
```

The `void ColorCmdExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)`, `void ColorCmdCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)` are defined in the **MainWindow.cs**.

How to change the XAML if I move these two handlers to **xxxx.cs** ?

*Edit, Add more info*

Command handlers are defined in **MainWindow.cs**, I cut and paste the code to another file as following, Then the compilation goes error. **Error CS1061 'MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'ColorCmdExecuted'**

```cs
// xxxx.cs
namespace CustomRoutedCommand
{
    public class xxxx
    {
        // ExecutedRoutedEventHandler for the custom color command.
        private void ColorCmdExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var target = e.Source as Panel;
            if (target != null)
            {
                target.Background = target.Background == Brushes.AliceBlue ? Brushes.LemonChiffon : Brushes.AliceBlue;
            }
        }

        // CanExecuteRoutedEventHandler for the custom color command.
        private void ColorCmdCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Source is Panel)
            {
                e.CanExecute = true;
            }
            else
            {
                e.CanExecute = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you sure you wanna use `Static` Command? and coming to question you can move it wt is the problem?

Comment: Not sure actually, I am a WPF beginner. I accept any better recommendations. And, There is an error when I move the "ColorCmdExecuted" to another file. **Error CS1061 'MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'ColorCmdExecuted'**

Comment: can post the moved file too. I mean where u placed that file code .

Comment: Create a new class(xxxx.cs) in the same namespace, Cut the code from MainWindow.cs and paste it to xxxx.cs.

Comment: Could you post a bit more code from the new file? Particularly, are these commands still part of `MainWindow` or are you defining a completely different class?

Comment: I updated my question, have I missed something? I have not used WPF command before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't move the acual event handlers that you hook up in the XAML markup to another class, but you could implement the logic in another class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static RoutedCommand ColorCmd = new RoutedCommand();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ColorCmdExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        xxxx.ColorCmdExecuted(e.Source);
    }

    private void ColorCmdCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = xxxx.ColorCmdCanExecute(e.Source);
    }
}

public class xxxx
{
    public static void ColorCmdExecuted(object parameter)
    {
        var target = parameter as Panel;
        if (target != null)
        {
            target.Background = target.Background == Brushes.AliceBlue ? Brushes.LemonChiffon : Brushes.AliceBlue;
        }
    }

    public static bool ColorCmdCanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return parameter is Panel;
    }
}
```

You may want to replace the `RoutedCommand` with a custom implementation of the `ICommand` interface that can perform some action when you execute the command directly:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> _execute;
    private Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_canExecute == null)
            return true;
        return _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_execute != null)
            _execute(parameter);
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static RelayCommand ColorCmd = new RelayCommand(xxxx.ColorCmdExecuted, null);

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class xxxx
{
    public static void ColorCmdExecuted(object parameter)
    {
        var target = parameter as Panel;
        if (target != null)
        {
            target.Background = target.Background == Brushes.AliceBlue ? Brushes.LemonChiffon : Brushes.AliceBlue;
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Button Command="{x:Static local:MainWindow.ColorCmd}" Content="CommandTarget = FristStackPanel" />
```

Please refer to [this](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/06/30/handling-events-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application/) blog post for more information about the concept.

Answer (score 0):

You could continue to use `static` commands, but it is much more common to see an implementation of `ICommand` used called `RelayCommand`. This allows us to utilize the MVVM a little more easily so your view model model can take care of the commands. Here's a basic example implementation of `ICommand`:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    private Action<object> _execute;

    public RelayCommand(Predicate<object> canExecute, Action<object> execute)
    {
        _canExecute = canExecute;
        _execute = execute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

Then, you would add the `RelayCommand` as a property to your view model such as like this:

```
public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private RelayCommand colorCmd;
    public ICommand ColorCmd
    {
        get
        {
            colorCmd ?? colorCmd = new RelayCommand(p => ColorCmdCanExecute(), p => ColorCmdExectued());
            return colorCmd;
        }
    }

    private bool ColorCmdCanExecute()
    {
        //CanExecute code here
        ...
    }

    private void ColorCmdExecuted()
    {
        //Command execute code here
        ...
    }
}
```

For more information on MVVM and `ICommand` implementation, there are lots of resources. [This one](https://intellitect.com/getting-started-model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-pattern-using-windows-presentation-framework-wpf/) is pretty easy to understand for a WPF beginner and should give you a bit more insight on how to proceed.